# Awk: Editing blocks of data individually

Tags: awk

I have text files that are subdivided in blocks and look something like this:

> foo: a
>      bar: b
>      bat: c
>
> foo: d
>      bar: e
>      bat: f
>
> ...

Is there a way that I can edit each block individually(i.e. run a set of rules for the block and then move to the next block)?
The result should look something like this:

> foo: a b
>      bar: b c
>      bat: c
>
> foo: d e
>      bar: e f
>      bat: f
>
> ...

I don't see how I can achieve this with rules that apply to the whole file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk` you can set the record separator and field separator to whatever you need. By default the field separator is whitespace and the recond separator is `\n`. You want to set the record separator to be a empty line and the field separator to be a `:`.

```
awk '{printf "%s:%s%s\n%s:%s%s\n%s:%s\n\n",$1,$2,$4,$3,$4,$6,$5,$6}' FS=: RS= file
foo: a b
bar: b c
bat: c

foo: d e
bar: e f
bat: f
```

You didn't state what you are trying to do and I'm guessing the data transformation is just an example so they may be a better approach.

Comment: Yes, the actual data is a bit more complex, but I think this is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

does this work for you?

```
awk -v RS="" -F'\n' '{for(i=1;i<=NF-1;i++){split($(i+1),x," ");$i=$i" "x[2];print $i}print $NF;print RS}' file
```

with your data:

```
kent$  echo "foo: a
bar: b
bat: c

foo: d
bar: e
bat: f"|awk -v RS="" -F'\n' '{for(i=1;i<=NF-1;i++){split($(i+1),x," ");$i=$i" "x[2];print $i}print $NF;print RS}'              
foo: a b
bar: b c
bat: c

foo: d e
bar: e f
bat: f
```